# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\WPTC-PMS5-5-14\edit_column.php on line 12

Tags: php

when the below code works I get the above mentioned error , what should i do ? please help me ...

```
<?php
 //session_start();
 include("dbconnect_database.php");
 $tname=$_GET['tn'];
 $cname=$_GET['cn'];
 $des=mysql_query("desc `$tname` `$cname`");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($des);
 list($type, $b) = explode('[(]',$row[1]);
 list($size) = explode('[)]',$b);
 ?>
```

Comment: And line 12 is where?

Comment: Your error message refers to line 12 but there are only *ten* lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
list($type, $b) = explode('[(]',$row[1]);
```

to this:

```
list($type, $b) = explode('[(]',$row[0]);
```

**UPDATE**

The error is telling you that `1` is not a valid index for `$row`, so that is the problem. Just before that line, try `var_dump($row)`. This will tell what the valid indexes for `$row` are, and you should be able to use that to fix your code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , but iam still getting the error message "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\WPTC-PMS5-5-14\edit_column.php on line 12"

Answer (score -1):

there is no `'` around `table` and `column` name

```
$des=mysql_query("desc $tname $cname");
```

sidenote: use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql` because use of mysql is been deprecated

Comment: If you recommend *mysqli* over *mysql*, why does your answer contain *mysql* extension functions? Also, OP uses backticks, not single-quotes

Comment: @Phil question was asked using MYSQL

Comment: So what? What is your motivation for providing answers on SO if it's not to educate?